# Passenger Error: No such file or directory - config/environment.rb on JustHost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, passenger

I am setting up new ruby website on justhot.com with default ruby(ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 MBARI 8/0x6770 on patchlevel 358) [x86_64-linux]) and rails[Rails 2.3.11] version. But I am getting the error even for any new application I am creating.

Below is the error:

Error message:
    No such file or directory - config/environment.rb
    [Complete error here: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/5958082]

I created directory rails_apps in root directory. I created ruby applications i.e redx by control panel in development mode with postgre database.

I have also created database and added user and updated database.yml file.

I also created symlinks:
**ln -s ~/rails_apps/redx/public ~/public_html/redx**
and 
**ln -s ~/rails_apps/redx ~/public_html/redx_app** [Purpose: for browsing files by ftp client]

I updated .htaccess in public folder i.e  ~/rails_apps/redx/public/.htaccess

I followed justhost article: https://my.justhost.com/cgi/help/207 to create .htaccess file and .bashrc

[.htaccess file]

```
Options -MultiViews
PassengerResolveSymlinksInDocumentRoot on
RailsEnv development
RailsBaseURI /
SetEnv GEM_HOME /home1/worthgur/ruby/gems
```

[I updated .bashrc here ~/.bashrc file]

```
export HPATH=$HOME
export GEM_HOME=$HPATH/ruby/gems
export GEM_PATH=$GEM_HOME:/usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8
export GEM_CACHE=$GEM_HOME/cache
export PATH=$PATH:$HPATH/ruby/gems/bin
export PATH=$PATH:$HPATH/ruby/gems
```

This is what I did. I created home controller also from ssh and that is doing good.
ruby script/generate controller home

I have also created file restart.txt in tmp folder of ruby application.

What else I need to do? What I am missing?

I have not done anything with vhost file as there was only ftpquota file in ~/etc

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of Phusion Passenger. You should upgrade to version 4, which probably solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

### This was not a problem of old version of Phusion Passenger.

This way problem fixed.

#### Step 1:

Since the system couldn't find the config/environment.rb and the root folder was /home1/worthgur, that indicated to me that it wasn't looking in the right place.
I went ahead and added the name of the symlink to the RailsBaseURI.  This is what it looked like after I edited that line:

RailsBaseURI /redx
*#redx is the symlink*
*#RailsBaseURI /redx changed from RailsBaseURI /*

#### Step 2:

After doing this error changed a little stating that it couldn't use rails 2.3.11 as it had already initialized rails 3.2, as a result I went into the home directory and added the config.ru file as Passenger documentation states that in order to run it needs 3 "entries" a config.ru file, a public folder, and a tmp folder.[Deploying a Rack application](http://www.modrails.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#deploying_a_rack_app)

Once that was done I went into the Gemfile and updated the rails gem with the version that I was running on the server.  After I did that the site loaded up without a problem.

Comment: What exactly did you added ? In config.ru file ?